# Is it possible to get selective combinations of dict in a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, combinations, python-itertools

While running with combinations in dict I have faced some difficulties, I have explained all this below.

```
name_list = {
      1 : {'_name' :'michael','id' : '001','rating': '10','role' :'general_manager'},
      2 : {'_name' :'mohamad','id' : '002','rating': '9.5','role' :'team_leader'},
      3 : {'_name' :'johnny','id' : '003','rating': '9','role' :'developer'},
      4 : {'_name' :'nicholos','id' : '004','rating': '9','role' :'tech_support'},
      5 : {'_name' :'nawaz','id' : '005','rating': '8.5','role' :'intern'}
}
new_list = {}
num =0
fab_four = combinations(name_list,4)

for i in range(len(fab_four)):
    j = new_list[i]
    for key, value in j.items():
        num= num+1
        new_list[num] = name_list[i]
```

My expected output:

```
new_list = {
    {
      1 : {'_name' :'michael','id' : '001','rating': '10','role' :'general_manager'},
      2 : {'_name' :'mohamad','id' : '002','rating': '9.5','role' :'team_leader'},
      3 : {'_name' :'johnny','id' : '003','rating': '9','role' :'developer'},
      4 : {'_name' :'nicholos','id' : '004','rating': '9','role' :'tech_support'}
    }
    ,
    {
      1 : {'_name' :'michael','id' : '001','rating': '10','role' :'general_manager'},
      2 : {'_name' :'mohamad','id' : '002','rating': '9.5','role' :'team_leader'},
      3 : {'_name' :'johnny','id' : '003','rating': '9','role' :'developer'},
      5 : {'_name' :'nawaz','id' : '005','rating': '8.5','role' :'intern'}
    }
}
```

Like expected output, I need all combinations in a new dict?

Comment: You haven't explained any of the difficulties you're having with your code.Is the output not what you expected, for examlpe? Are errors occurring> What?

Comment: @martineau no errors...i can able to get all combinations but while im iterating the output coming like {(1,2,3,4),(1,2,3,5)}....etc

Comment: I am getting an error with your code since the variable fab_four does not have a method len(), and after that you should get a key error for new_list[i].

Comment: that is the problem @ArvindKumar......the iteration part is not wrking for dict..when we took combinations

Comment: iterating through combination in a dict was the part i'm struggling @ArvindKumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the output you mentioned earlier using this:

```
new_list={}
fab_four = list(combinations(name_list,4))
for j in range(len(fab_four)):
    new_list[j+1] = {i:name_list[i] for i in fab_four[j]}
```

**Output:**

```
{1:{1: {'_name': 'michael', 'id': '001', 'rating': '10', 'role': 'general_manager'},
    2: {'_name': 'mohamad', 'id': '002', 'rating': '9.5', 'role': 'team_leader'},
    3: {'_name': 'johnny', 'id': '003', 'rating': '9', 'role': 'developer'},
    4: {'_name': 'nicholos', 'id': '004', 'rating': '9', 'role': 'tech_support'}},
2: {1: {'_name': 'michael', 'id': '001', 'rating': '10', 'role': 'general_manager'},
    2: {'_name': 'mohamad', 'id': '002', 'rating': '9.5', 'role': 'team_leader'},
    3: {'_name': 'johnny', 'id': '003', 'rating': '9', 'role': 'developer'},
    5: {'_name': 'nawaz', 'id': '005', 'rating': '8.5', 'role': 'intern'}},
3: {1: {'_name': 'michael', 'id': '001', 'rating': '10', 'role': 'general_manager'},
    2: {'_name': 'mohamad', 'id': '002', 'rating': '9.5', 'role': 'team_leader'},
    4: {'_name': 'nicholos', 'id': '004', 'rating': '9', 'role': 'tech_support'},
    5: {'_name': 'nawaz', 'id': '005', 'rating': '8.5', 'role': 'intern'}},
4: {1: {'_name': 'michael', 'id': '001', 'rating': '10', 'role': 'general_manager'},
    3: {'_name': 'johnny', 'id': '003', 'rating': '9', 'role': 'developer'},
    4: {'_name': 'nicholos', 'id': '004', 'rating': '9', 'role': 'tech_support'},
    5: {'_name': 'nawaz', 'id': '005', 'rating': '8.5', 'role': 'intern'}},
5: {2: {'_name': 'mohamad', 'id': '002', 'rating': '9.5', 'role': 'team_leader'},
    3: {'_name': 'johnny', 'id': '003', 'rating': '9', 'role': 'developer'},
    4: {'_name': 'nicholos', 'id': '004', 'rating': '9', 'role': 'tech_support'},
    5: {'_name': 'nawaz', 'id': '005', 'rating': '8.5', 'role': 'intern'}}}
```

Comment: are you sure about this @Arvind Kumar ...i got error like this while run through ur suggestion TypeError: object of type 'itertools.combinations' has no len()

Comment: yeah my bad, I missed the list() before combinations(name_list,4). Now it should work.